# Keep history of jobs executed for more than 1 day in Hangfire

Tags: hangfire

I've just started using Hangfire, and I am loving it.

I understand that Hangfire maintains the history for succeeded jobs for 1 day, and clear it thereafter.

Is there is a way where I can customize this default behavior and persist the history for any duration say 7 days?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To do this, you need to create a job filter and register it through hangfire global configurations, as discussed here - 
https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-configure-the-retention-time-of-job/34

Create job filter -

```
using Hangfire.Common;
using Hangfire.States;
using Hangfire.Storage;
using System;

namespace HangfireDemo
{
    public class ProlongExpirationTimeAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IApplyStateFilter
    {
        public void OnStateApplied(ApplyStateContext filterContext, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
        {
            filterContext.JobExpirationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
        }

        public void OnStateUnapplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
        {
            context.JobExpirationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
        }
    }
}
```

...and register in global job filters -

```
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new ProlongExpirationTimeAttribute());
```

Answer (score 2):

Copy from link https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-configure-the-retention-time-of-job/34 from Yogy:

> In the recent versions of Hangfire it is also possible to specify the
> expiration globally by using the WithJobExpirationTimeout method just
> after the UseXXXStorage (where XXX is the storage you are using) and
> pass the required timeout as an argument.

```
Configuration
.UseXXXStorage()
.WithJobExpirationTimeout(TimeSpan.FromDays(4))
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked for me. Here is a separate source as well - https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/index.html