# Set Hangfire succeeded job expiry attribute not working

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am using Hangfire to do jobs, and I'd like to change the behaviour that succeeded jobs are deleted from the database after a day - I'd like them to be stored for a year.

Following the instructions in this [thread](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-configure-the-retention-time-of-job/34), which is the same as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450884/keep-history-of-jobs-executed-for-more-than-1-day-in-hangfire), I have created a class:

```
public class OneYearExpirationTimeAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IApplyStateFilter
{
    public void OnStateUnapplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
    {
        context.JobExpirationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
    }

    public void OnStateApplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
    {
        context.JobExpirationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
    }
}
```

and I register it in my Asp.net web api startup class as a global filter:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // ... other stuff here ...
        GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new OneYearExpirationTimeAttribute());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HangFireDBConnection");
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    }
}
```

The web api is the place where jobs are posted (i.e., the call to `BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => ...)` happens). I have not changed the configuration of the clients that do the actual jobs.

If I now post a job and it succeeds, it still has a expiry of one day as you can see in the screenshot, which shows both the dashboard and the entry in the HangfireDb,

[image]

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: take a look at the last answer https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-configure-the-retention-time-of-job/34/11 you should configure `SQLServerStorage` class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep history of jobs executed for more than 1 day in Hangfire](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450884/keep-history-of-jobs-executed-for-more-than-1-day-in-hangfire)

Comment: @Alex this is not a duplicate. The OP's implementation is similar to the solution from that question but is still having problems.

Comment: @Alex adding the configuration in the `SQLServerStorage` class as shown in the link, `JobExpirationCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)`, only changes the interval for checking the job expiration, not the expiration itself, IMO.

Comment: Have you tried adding the attribute directly as an attribute instead of a global filter (just to test)? `[OneYearExpirationTime]public void SomeMethod()`

Comment: Do you have a multi server setup? I find it really surprising that it doesn't work, it should be pretty straightforward

Comment: @GôTô Yes, two servers. I just applied the attributes everywhere, job is runnng, will know in 5 mins ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My mistake in setup was that the attribute was set on the wrong application. As I stated in the question, I added the filter in the startup.cs file of the asp.net web api where jobs are posted.

Instead I should have added the configuration in the Console application where the jobs are being executed, i.e., my console app starts with

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HangFireDBConnection");
    GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new OneYearExpirationTimeAttribute());
    // ... more stuff ...
}
```

Then it works. The Hangfire documentation could be a bit clearer on where the filter should be configured.

Comment: Yes this information (that hangfire is not actually running in IIS) would have been very useful...

Answer (score 3):

Using version:

```
// Type: Hangfire.JobStorage
// Assembly: Hangfire.Core, Version=1.7.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

This can be done directly (apparently)

```cs
JobStorage.Current.JobExpirationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(6 * 7);
```

Comment: Or equivalently, use `.WithJobExpirationTimeout()` as stated [in the doc here](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/index.html#states).