# Hangfire Job timout

Tags: hangfire

I have certain jobs that appear to be 'Hung' in hangfire and may run for hours but aren't actually doing anything.  Is there a way for Hangfire to kill a job if it runs longer than a certain amount to time?

I'm running the latest version of Hangfire on SQL server.

Comment: You can probably set expiry for each job by writing a job filter. Explained here: https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-configure-the-retention-time-of-job/34/2 . Use "OnStateUnapplied()" to set the expiration time for all jobs.

Comment: one more link that can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485548/set-hangfire-succeeded-job-expiry-attribute-not-working

Answer (score 1):

In your job creation (doesn't matter if it's a recurring or a single background job) call, pass in an extra param of type "IJobCancellationToken" to your job method like this,

```
public static void Method1(string param1, IJobCancellationToken token) { }
```

When you create your job, create it with a null IJobCancellationToken token value and save the jobId. Have another recurring job that polls these jobs and simply call `BackgroundJob.Delete(jobId)` when it exceeds your desired time limit. This will clear the job from hangfire and also kill the process on your server.

> Reference: https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-cancel-a-job/872

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, you'll want to set the FetchNextJobTimeout at startup. By setting FetchNextJobTimeout, you can control how long a job can run for before Hangfire starts executing it again on another thread.

```
services.AddHangfire(config => {
       config.UseMemoryStorage(new MemoryStorageOptions { FetchNextJobTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(24) });
});
```